# Find the number of retransmitted packets

Tags: linux, tcp, tcpdump

I am using tcp_info to print out the information about a specific socket.
I am using tcpi_total_retrans to print out the total number of the retransmitted packets. However, when I compared the result to tcpdump result of the number of retransmitted packets it is different (tcpi_total_retrans shows larger number than tcpdump). Any ideas why is that happening? Isn't tcpi_total_retrans suppose to calculate the total number of the retransmitted packets?
I am modifying a code for a tool called BWdetail to print out the total number of retransmitted packets, you can find the tool code [here](http://www.ece.virginia.edu/cheetah/software/software.html).
Also, I am running tcpdump just before running the tool, then killing it directly after the tool finished running.
This is tcpdump output:

```
 a->b:                b->a:
     total packets:         81852           total packets:        130675      
     ack pkts sent:         81852           ack pkts sent:        130675      
     pure acks sent:            0           pure acks sent:       130675      
     sack pkts sent:            0           sack pkts sent:            0      
     dsack pkts sent:           0           dsack pkts sent:           0      
     max sack blks/ack:         0           max sack blks/ack:         0      
     unique bytes sent: 1088069192           unique bytes sent:         0      
     actual data pkts:      81852           actual data pkts:          0      
     actual data bytes: 1088083672           actual data bytes:         0      
     rexmt data pkts:          10           rexmt data pkts:           0      
     rexmt data bytes:      14480           rexmt data bytes:          0      
     zwnd probe pkts:           0           zwnd probe pkts:           0      
     zwnd probe bytes:          0           zwnd probe bytes:          0      
     outoforder pkts:           0           outoforder pkts:           0      
     pushed data pkts:       2737           pushed data pkts:          0      
     SYN/FIN pkts sent:       0/0           SYN/FIN pkts sent:       0/0      
     req 1323 ws/ts:          N/Y           req 1323 ws/ts:          N/Y      
     urgent data pkts:          0 pkts      urgent data pkts:          0 pkts 
     urgent data bytes:         0 bytes     urgent data bytes:         0 bytes
     mss requested:             0 bytes     mss requested:             0 bytes
     max segm size:         33304 bytes     max segm size:             0 bytes
     min segm size:          1448 bytes     min segm size:             0 bytes
     avg segm size:         13293 bytes     avg segm size:             0 bytes
     max win adv:             192 bytes     max win adv:             232 bytes
     min win adv:             192 bytes     min win adv:             181 bytes
     zero win adv:              0 times     zero win adv:              0 times
     avg win adv:             192 bytes     avg win adv:             228 bytes
     initial window:        17376 bytes     initial window:            0 bytes
     initial window:            1 pkts      initial window:            0 pkts 
     ttl stream length:        NA           ttl stream length:        NA      
     missed data:              NA           missed data:              NA      
     truncated data:    1087756264 bytes     truncated data:            0 bytes
     truncated packets:     81852 pkts      truncated packets:         0 pkts 
     data xmit time:        9.986 secs      data xmit time:        0.000 secs 
     idletime max:           15.7 ms        idletime max:           15.3 ms   
     throughput:        108955360 Bps       throughput:                0 Bps
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you seeing packets dropped by the kernel when `tcpdump` reports is statistics at the end?

Comment: @ezpz I am not sure.. I added tcpdump output above, you can have a look at it.. Thank you

Comment: That looks like `tcptrace` output. What I was inquiring about was what `tcpdump` itself reports. An example would look like:

`1 packet captured
11 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel`

You would see this output when you kill the `tcpdump` process.